# can't access apache2 on docker from my localhost (ubuntu os)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, docker

I am trying to access apache installed on docker from local host but can't access. below is dockerfile contents

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
RUN rm -f index.html
RUN touch index.html
RUN echo "welcome" > index.html
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04.
Used this command to run docker `docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 imageName`

Container is up and running and also pointing port
`0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`

I am able to access apache2 on local machine without docker but can't access apache2 installed on docker container.

please help :)

Comment: For a start, with the default config, Apache listens on port 80 so your `docker run` should be `-p 8080:80`. Same remark for your EXPOSE.

Comment: thanks xenoid, that worked. I didn't configured apache to listen on 8080.